# How to get first level children via querySelectorAll(selector)

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors, children

If we have a UL list with nested UL lists like

```
<ul>
    <li>Item
        <ul>
            <li>Subitem</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and we need to get all the LI elements of the first level only, we can use `querySelectorAll()` the way like:

```
let firstLevelChildren = document.querySelectorAll('ul > li');
```

But what if I create the UL list via `document.createElement('ul')` and need to get the first level children of such specific node via `querySelectorAll(selector)`?

Is there a selector?

I know about `node.children`, but I need a way via `querySelectorAll()`.

There may be any unknown number of the first level children. Also there may be different cases like `'> li > ul'` and so on.

The way like:

```
let ul = document.createElement('ul');
ul.innerHTML = '<li>Item<ul><li>Subitem</li></ul></li>';
let items = ul.querySelectorAll('> li');
console.log(items);
```

throws the error

> ' > li' is not a valid selector.

Comment: Why should this be done with `.querySelectorAll()` specifically? Why not `.children`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `:scope`

```js
let ul = document.createElement('ul');
ul.innerHTML = `
  <li>
    Item
    <ul>
      <li>Subitem</li>
    </ul>
  </li>`;
let items = ul.querySelectorAll(':scope > li');
document.body.appendChild(ul)
console.log(items.length + ' first level item(s)');
```